# Get the SUM of one column when grouped by another column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 fields

```
ID  Tax   State
0   .50   TX
1   .25   TX
2   .25   AZ
3   .25   AZ
4   .1    AL
```

I want to pull the sum of Tax for each state.

```
Tax   State
.75   TX
.5    AZ
.1    AL
```

How would I write a query to do this?

Answer (score 26):

This is a really rudimentary `SUM()` aggregate.  I recommend reading your RDBMS' documentation on aggregate functions and `GROUP BY` because this is quite elementary.

```
SELECT
  SUM(Tax) AS sumtax,
  State
FROM table
GROUP BY State
/* Looks like you want descending order */
ORDER BY SUM(Tax) DESC
```

Note that some RDBMS (MySQL, for instance) will allow you to use a column alias in the `ORDER BY` as in:

```
ORDER BY sumtax DESC
```

... where others (Like SQL Server if I recall correctly) will not and you must use the aggregate value there too.

**Edit:** *I just checked and actually SQL Server does seem to allow aliases in the `ORDER BY`. Pretty sure you can't use an alias in the `GROUP BY` though...*

Comment: @dadan The ID is not unique for each `SUM()` aggregate because multiple state ID values are represented in each `SUM()`.  (for example `TX` sum has ids 0, 1) You should post a question demonstrating exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks for answering, i have found solution for my problem, using `over partition by` on oracle